# How to prevent Windows Narrator from saying "editable text" for every HTML tag on role="alert" in FF

Tags: firefox, accessibility, wai-aria, narrator

I have this simple live region:

```
<div aria-atomic="true" role="alert" id="AlertText"></div>
```

Now in FF+Windows Narrator the live region works fine I change the text and the alert come like it's supposed to. However the original alert text is actually quite complex and long with BR and H2 tags. The problem is that every time a close tag is reached in the text the alert says "editable text".

I thought of moving the alert to a hidden live region without the tags but even then although the alert worked just fine, when it reached the end tag of the alert role div (i.e. DIV#AlertText in my example) it said "editable text" in FF.

Now in IE it does not have this problem and the MacOS Narrator does not have it as well and its simply confusing.

I am afraid that someone would hear it and think it's a text input or something (though granted it says "editing text" on a text input field).

I would prefer to have the original container as the alert role, but I simply can't have it saying "editing text" several times, or is that normal and FF users are used to it... any help on this is appreciated.

I am currently developing on the Win8.1 Narrator.

**EDIT:** Example of the live code in an isolated HTML (however I did not seam to get this example to work in Win Narrator)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Role Alert Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="btnAlert" href="#">Set Text</button>
        <div aria-atomic="true" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="additions text">
            <div class="AccessibleVersion-OverviewHeadingContainer">
                <h2 class="AccessibleVersion-SubHeading" id="AccessibleVersion-SubHeading-Overview">Overview</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="AccessibleVersion-OverviewTextContainer" aria-labelledby="AccessibleVersion-SubHeading-Overview" id="overviewText"></div>
            <br />
            <h2 class="AccessibleVersion-SubHeading" id="AccessibleVersion-SubHeading-OverviewHistory">Annual dividend history for the last five years</h2>
            <div id="annualDividendText" aria-labelledby="AccessibleVersion-SubHeading-OverviewHistory"></div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById('btnAlert').onclick = function() {
                var dom = document.getElementById('overviewText');

                dom.appendChild(document.createTextNode("The latest dividend of Almarai Company for Almarai is equal to 1.00 Saudi Riyal per share. The ex-date was on 06/04/2015 and it was paid on 14/04/2015. The dividend type is Annual."));
                dom.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                dom.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Current dividend yield is equal to 1.90 percent."));
                dom.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                dom.appendChild(document.createTextNode("52 weeks dividend sum is equal to 1.00 Saudi Riyal."));
                dom.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                dom.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Total return, calculated with dividends reinvested, is equal to -38 percent for the past 12 months and +62 percent for the past 3 years."));


                dom = document.getElementById('annualDividendText');
                dom.appendChild(document.createTextNode("2011: total dividend 1.50 Saudi Riyal, dividend yield (based on year-end share price) 3.91 percent."));
                dom.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                dom.appendChild(document.createTextNode("2012: total dividend 0.83 Saudi Riyal, dividend yield 1.96 percent."));
                dom.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                dom.appendChild(document.createTextNode("2013: total dividend 1.00 Saudi Riyal, dividend yield 1.90 percent."));
                dom.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                dom.appendChild(document.createTextNode("2014: total dividend 1.00 Saudi Riyal, dividend yield 1.30 percent."));

            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a sample to try?  What happens with JAWS, NVDA, or Voiceover?

Comment: @slugolicious I checked it out in VoiceOver and JAWS it's fine i.e. how it is supposed to be, but for some reason the NVDA does not want to install on my computer. I added in an isoladed HTML for you, but I can't seam to get it's alert to work for some reason in Narrator although the code is the same... still hope it helps.